# re-ordering/unwraping integer pairs efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, graph-theory

It is a bit hard to explain what I want to do, so the best way is to show an example I think.
I have a 2D numpy array which contains a list of integer pairs. Those integers go from 0 to N and each appears in 2 pairs of the list, except for two of them (which will be called the extrema). So the list contains N-1 pairs.

I would like to reorder the array to have it starting by one of the pair containing an extremum, and having the next pair starting by the previous pair end... very confusing so look at this example : 
I start with this array :

```
array([[3, 0], [3, 2], [4, 0], [1, 2]])
```

and I would like to end up with this one :

```
array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0], [0, 4]])
```

here is a algorithm that works but which contains a loop over N-1... in this case it is not a problem since N=5 but I would like to do it with N=100000 or more so I would like to do it without an explicit python loop but can't figure out a way...

```
import numpy as np

co = np.array([[3, 0], [3, 2], [4, 0], [1, 2]])
extrema = np.nonzero(np.bincount(co.flat) == 1)[0]

nb_el = co.shape[0]
new_co = np.empty_like(co)
start = extrema[0]
for el_idx in xrange(nb_el):
    where_idx = np.where(co == start)
    if where_idx[1][0] == 1:
        new_co[el_idx] = co[where_idx[0][0]][::-1]
    else:
        new_co[el_idx] = co[where_idx[0][0]]
    co = np.delete(co, where_idx[0], 0)
    start = new_co[el_idx][-1]

print new_co
# array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0], [0, 4]])
```

Comment: if it simplifies the problem (I dont think it does) I actually only need to retrieve the list ``[1, 2, 3, 0, 4]``. which is basically the list of ``starts`` and the last extremum

Comment: This smells like a homework assignment.

Comment: I think you have to do an iterative construction like this.  But you may speed it up with `in1d` instead of `where`, and avoiding the  repeated `np.delete` (a relatively expensive copy).  Sort or argsort on one or both columns might also help.

Comment: What you're looking for is known as an [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) in graph theory. You can think of each row in your array as specifying an edge in an undirected graph (i.e. 1 is connected to 2, 2 is connected to 3 etc.). You're looking for a path that visits every edge in the graph exactly once. [Fleury's algorithm](https://www.austincc.edu/powens/+Topics/HTML/05-6/05-6.html) is guaranteed to find such a path provided that one exists.

Comment: Ok thank you for the info, I'm gonna look into it

Comment: If i'm not mistaken what I implemented is already the fleury algorithm... I start from an extremum node use a path to find next node and remove the path used from the graph and do it till I cover all the paths.